FluentAssertions: How to get the context printed correctly within custom EquivalencyStep
In my application I use a custom PaginatedList<T> class that extends List with some extra properties. Given that FluentAssertion only compares the content of the list and excludes extra properties when using BeEquivalentTo(), I wrote my own EquivalencyStep to check the extra property manually. However, I can't get it to print the name of the properties properly.
Here is a minimal (not) working example:
Models:
public interface IPaginatedList {
    int CurrentPage { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    int ItemsCount { get; }
}

public sealed class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>, IPaginatedList {
    public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> items, int currentPage, int pageSize, int itemsCount) {
        this.CurrentPage = currentPage;
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.ItemsCount = itemsCount;

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public int CurrentPage { get; }

    public int PageSize { get; }

    public int ItemsCount { get; }
}

public sealed class Result<T> {
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public T? ValueOrDefault { get; set; }
}


EquivalencyStep:
public sealed class PaginatedListEquivalencyStep : EquivalencyStep<IPaginatedList> {
    protected override EquivalencyResult OnHandle(Comparands comparands, IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator nestedValidator) {
        if (comparands.Subject is not IPaginatedList subject) {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        if (comparands.Expectation is not IPaginatedList expectation) {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        // Assert custom properties
        using (new AssertionScope($"{context.CurrentNode.Description}.{nameof(subject.ItemsCount)}")) {
            subject.ItemsCount.Should().Be(expectation.ItemsCount);
        }

        // [...]

        // Assert that the content of the collection is the same
        new EnumerableEquivalencyStep().Handle(comparands,
            context,
            nestedValidator);

        return EquivalencyResult.AssertionCompleted;
    }
}

Program:
Result<PaginatedList<int>> result = new() {
    IsSuccess = true,
    ValueOrDefault = new PaginatedList<int>(
        [1, 2, 3],
        1,
        3,
        3
    )
};

Result<PaginatedList<int>> expected = new() {
    IsSuccess = true,
    ValueOrDefault = new PaginatedList<int>(
        [1, 2, 3],
        1,
        3,
        10 // This value is diferent: should fail.
    )
};

result.Should()
    .BeEquivalentTo(
        expected,
        opt => opt
            .Using(new PaginatedListEquivalencyStep()));

Expected error message:
Expected property result.ValueOrDefault.ItemsCount to be 10, but found 3 (difference of -7)
What it actually prints:
Expected property using (new AssertionScope($"{context.CurrentNode.Description}.{nameof(subject.ItemsCount)}")) {subject.ItemsCount.ValueOrDefault.ItemsCount to be 10, but found 3 (difference of -7).
What is even stranger is that adding .WithTrace() in the equivalency options has the side effect of correcting the property name and displaying the right thing.
Is it a bug, or am I missing something there?

can't reproduce with FluentAssertions 6.12.0 and .NET6. I get what you expect. although not result but root Expected property root.ValueOrDefault.ItemsCount to be 10, but found 3 (difference of -7).

You don't get really what I expect then.
I'm using FluentAssertions 6.12.0 too, but .Net 8.
I just tested using .Net6, in debug mode I get the same message than with .Net8. In release mode I get "root" just like you, which is still wrong...
What's even more confusing is that, with .Net8, when setting a breakpoint inside my EquivalencyStep and inspecting the value of context, it prints "root" at the end
